Share specific folder between macOS and Linux
Using macOS Sonoma 14.7.1 on MacBook Air M1, I want to share a specific folder with my Linux desktop (Linux Mint 22).
I have enabled file sharing in macOS and I've set the password for a specific user:

On Linux though, I can access all the user's home directory, the main hard drive not just the folder I wanted to share.
How can I limit sharing to a specific folder (i.e. Downloads)?

Is the "user" an administrator on the Mac?  Administrators can see all volumes.

Yes the user is an administrator. So I can't just share a specific folder right?
I guess I had to create a new user for this...

In that case, I will make it an answer.

All Administrators can access all volumes on a Mac with file sharing enabled. This is mentioned at the top of the file sharing pane where it says:

Other users can access shared folders on this computer, and administrators all volumes, at smb://192.168.1.99

The file sharing help (click the ? at bottom left) is a good description of controlling file sharing.
To control access to specific shares, create a non-administrator username on the shared Mac.
Optionally, this username can be restricted to just network access (no interactive login) when creating. To do this set the new user type to "Sharing Only" in this window:

